# Stack Snippets asking whether to abandon changes or not, when there are none

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

I clicked the `Code Snippet` button above a post by mistake- thinking it'll open the existing snippet.

Instead it opened a new snippet widow, as it should. I realized my mistake and tried to close it, which prompted me

[image: current output]

When there was no changes at all.

Can we get rid of this (*if there are no changes*)..?

Comment: Cheap fix: just change the copy to "Are you sure you want to abandon *any* changes?" which would leave open the possibility that there were none.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing this out. Due to the way our external editor works, I have opted for the *cheap* fix of changing the wording to the following:

> Are you sure you want to abandon any changes?

This will be live in the next build (meta: > `rev 2014.10.2.2623`, q&a: > `rev 2014.10.2.1907`).