# Cannot create Stack Snippet

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

I've tried in Chrome and Internet Explorer on my machine here, and it will not let me insert a snippet. I press the <kbd>Insert into post</kbd> button and nothing happens. Even here on MSO it's not working.

There doesn't seem to be any JavaScript errors in the Chrome console either.

To add as much information as possible. My steps. In the answer box press the `Code Snippet` button or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, enter anything you like into the available boxes and press the <kbd>Insert into post</kbd> button. Note that NOTHING happens.

I have now tried on two browsers on my work laptop (Chrome and IE in Windows 8.1) and form my home computer (Chrome on Windows 8.1), both without a proxy server (unless the ISPs are both interfering somehow transparently)

I have tried disabling AdBlock, TamperMonkey etc (even though they were not affecting my IE session)

Additionally, as @JaredReeves suggested in the comments, if you click outside of the popup window instead of pressing the insert button, the code does get inserted correctly.

---

Screenshot of the issue, shared by KyleMit:

> [image]

Comment: Hum. Seeing same thing here (though first time I try that feature). Got an error in the console when trying to run the snippet (after failing to insert into the post): POST http://stacksnippets.net/js net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE ; Chrome 37.0.2062.124 m.

Comment: @Mat Oddly I'm not seeing that error.

Comment: Well, I'm behind a somewhat barbarian firewall right now, so... strange that we can't see any error on the insert button though.

Comment: @Haney Seeing same issue. Can run it when writing but insert into post fails with no console errors. Affects Firefox too.

Comment: Might've broke when Haney fixed [this wording](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272654/stack-snippets-asking-whether-to-abandon-changes-or-not-when-there-are-none) somehow. I've seen stranger breaks from small changes. :/

Comment: Repro here.  See this in the console:  Uncaught SecurityError: Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at "http://stacksnippets.net" from accessing a frame at "http://meta.stackoverflow.com".  The frame requesting access is sandboxed and lacks the "allow-same-origin" flag.

Comment: @Will I don't see that error, where are you getting it from?

Comment: It shows up when I hit the Run button.  Add stupid example, hit run, error shows, insert into post, nothing.  Might have nothing to do with the repro, not sure.

Comment: @Will It seems to perfectly apply to the issue but I can't repro your repro. Do you have any funky Chrome options turned on?

Comment: Yeah, probably.  If no repro with others, it may be extension/userscript related.

Comment: Also having this problem with chrome on windows 7. Adblock also disabled.

Comment: @DavidG I am experiencing the same thing, however, when I click out side the code window, the content is actually placed in the post. It just looks like it is not working. Is this happening for you as well. Note: it was working correctly for me yesterday

Comment: @DavidG : By the way, do you use a proxy for connecting *(even a transparent one)*?

Comment: Using Firefox and Chrome both latest versions in Win OS with direct internet connection, and not working as well, it was working a few hours ago.

Comment: not working for me in Firefox either, just stalled trying to load content from stacksnippets.net . No proxy

Comment: Same here in Chrome mac 37.0.2062.124

Comment: @user2284570 You said you aren't having this issue- Out of curiousity and because it might interest Haney or whoever else looks later, what browser and OS are you using? I ask because it looks like a very mixed lot so far in the comments here. I'm currently using IE11 and Windows 7 myself with no addons.

Comment: @Kendra : `Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64; Edition Next) Presto/2.12.378 Version/12.50`. `3.7.3-alt330-amd64 #2 SMP`

Comment: @user2284570 There's really nothing I can add. Screenshots will not help. Add anything I like to the snippet popup, press "insert into post" and nothing happens. I'll update the question with as much detail as I can.

Comment: @JaredReeves Interesting point! Clicking outside of the popup window does insert the code correctly.

Comment: The same is happening on CodeReview: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2575/14625

Comment: @tomdemuyt : Since this issue is common to several sites, then the right place to discuss about in is on the [StackExchange meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239747/242800).

Comment: If I tell my devtools to pause execution on all exceptions, it pauses on a DOMException every 5 seconds or so. Chrome.

Comment: @DavidG : Some details about your configuration. By example I had the [exact symptoms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239747/242800) you described *(computer configured to use a direct connection)*. I finally figured out the transparent proxy *(you can even don't notice it exist)* which it used to log connections. I also figured some ISP use this method for logging users's metadata. Does it work if you [edit my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/272781/edit) using https on IE or FF?

Comment: @user2284570 Your problem is not the exact same symptoms, it's not even the same problem. The details of my configuration were irrelevant at the time because I had tested it on multiple devices using multiple service providers. If it was a transparent proxy then 3 distinct ISPs in the UK, including one mobile operator would have had to have implemented it at the same time. Additionally, pasting code from the editor into the answer box requires no client/server interaction so proxy cannot be the issue.

Comment: Central bug report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240486/snippets-editor-wont-insert-and-close-on-so?noredirect=1#comment788101_240486

Comment: @JaredReeves: Thank you for that. I can confirm that clicking outside the frame works for me, too.

Comment: I was *just* about to post my first inline snippet rather than use jsfiddle, how disappointing! Looking forward to a fix.

Comment: @WesleyMurch You can still do it, just click outside the window instead.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either, but it was working fine until 2 days ago or so. How to reproduce the problem? Create a snippet and click the button to insert it into the answer. Nothing happens, no errors in the browser console. Cracking on with `jsFiddle` in the meantime.

Comment: @MelanciaUK : Yes, and by following the same steps I can't see anything wrong. So your description lack some informations/circumstances. Otherwise I would be able to reproduce it.

Comment: @DavidG : `Additionally, pasting code from the editor into the answer box requires no client/server interaction so proxy cannot be the issue.` Stacks Snippet need to provide security in order to prevent cross site scripting. I tried on a different port *(A redirected port which allow to bypass the proxy and by still using the same puclic address)* and it worked. The same thing append with https because of the encryption.

Comment: @user2284570 No, the security is taken care of in the running, not the creation.

Comment: @user2284570 Believe me. I've been working with Web development for at least 17 years. If this happened on a unusual circumstance I would have pointed out. It's that simple. Nothing special about my broadband, my browser or even the contents in the snippet (basic HTML, CSS and Javascript/jQuery). Tried on Chrome, Firefox (both latest versions) and IE 11.

Comment: @user2284570 I don't really understand why you keep asking for more detail - there is nothing else to add. Just because you apparently are not suffering from the same problem doesn't mean everyone else isn't. Perhaps YOU should be giving US more info as to why it's working only for you?

Comment: [Screenshot of it not working in Chrome](http://i.imgur.com/6hm12Us.gif)

Comment: I tried these in console: `$("input[value='► Run']").length` gives `1`, `$("input[value='Insert into Post']").length` gives `1` too; `$("input[value='► Run']").click()` actually runs my snippet, but `$("input[value='Insert into Post']").click()` does nothing. Using Opera 24.0.1558.64 on Mac OS X 10.9.5. Sorry, can't help more as all JS are obfuscated.

Comment: Same here on Opera v24 with no proxies on Windows 8.

Comment: @user2284570: Did you clear _your_ cache? Maybe you're still running the old, working version of the site.

Comment: @Cerbrus : Yes, I even disabled the cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Haney's back from vacation. See [his answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240709/134069), he's patched the issue and the fix will be live in the next production release (meta: > rev 2014.10.7.2635, q&a: > rev 2014.10.7.1918).

Comment: Thanks T.J. and sorry everyone for the inconvenience. I feel bad about it. :(

Comment: @Haney: Give yourself a break. Everyone paying attention knows the good work you do. :-)

Answer (score 10):

## **EDIT 10/07/2014**

Found that the event attached to the **"Insert into Post"** button was actually a `click()`method on the `#lightbox`element *("the grayed background" in my first edit)*

Then I found that the function attached to this background is declared in [http://`anyStackExchangeURI`/content/Js/snippet-javascript.en.js?v=a1ab680d4e77](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Js/snippet-javascript.en.js?v=a1ab680d4e77)

*original function attached to background's `onmousedown` event :*

 
`e("#lightbox").mousedown(function(){var n=e(this).next("div").find(".popup"),i=n.data("_snippet"),a=i.save();if(""==a.html&&""==a.css&&""==a.js)return t.addSnippetToEditor(null),void 0;var o=r(a);t.addSnippetToEditor(o,o)})`

After long reading of all the scripts loaded, I finally figured out what all of these shortnamed variables were meaning.

So here is a hard written function that can be executed in console when the snippet editor is ready.

**This is just for demonstration, @DavidG has a better script for any greasemonkey workaround and @JaredReeves solution is still a good one until devs fix it

```
function o(e, t, n) {
  return e.replace(/^(?=.)/gm, new Array(t * n + 1).join(' '))
}
function r(e) {
  var t = '\n\n<!-- begin snippet: js hide: ' + e.hide + ' -->\n\n';
  return '' != e.js && (t += '<!-- language: lang-js -->\n\n' + o(e.js, 1, 4) + '\n\n'),
  '' != e.css && (t += '<!-- language: lang-css -->\n\n' + o(e.css, 1, 4) + '\n\n'),
  '' != e.html && (t += '<!-- language: lang-html -->\n\n' + o(e.html, 1, 4) + '\n\n'),
  t += '<!-- end snippet -->\n\n'
}
$('#lightbox').click(function () {
  var n = $(this).next('div').find('.popup');
  var i = n.data('_snippet'),
  a = i.save();
  var o = r(a);
  window.addSnippetToEditor(o, o)
});
```

## First Post

Even if **it is not a solution**, @JaredReeves found a **quick** workaround  :

While Editing the snippet, click in the grayed background page : [image]

```js
console.log(7357)
```

```html
This is a test
```

Comment: Yes, that is mentioned in the question.

Comment: @DavidG Right, Didn't noticed as I first read the post friday. Could you make it more visible in your question ?

Comment: Awesome -- testing it now.  Perhaps someone could write a chrome extension to hook the [Insert into Post] click event and trigger the click event that is on the zone you have highlighted.

Comment: @SanuelJackson Actually it is what the SE code does. The click() event doesn't trigger however. I don't know what is blocking it in the function : as it has been said, the code is obfuscated and when you try to launch edited codes, it redownloads original ones, overriding any of my efforts… Maybe I'll put a little more time on it but not now…

Comment: I've done a little digging in the js. The suggestion by @SanuelJackson is actually how this is **supposed** to work. There is a bit of script on the insert button saying `e("#lightbox").click()` and `#lightbox` is the element behind the snippet editor. Not had enough time to figure out why that event is not being bound to the button though, maybe when I've got more time!

Comment: Updated the answer, feel free to add your extension codes

Comment: You could replace that whole lot of js with: `$('input[value="Insert into Post"]').click(function() { $("#lightbox").trigger('mousedown'); });`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is 100% correct so won't accept my own answer until one of the devs responds but it seems the code behind the <kbd>Insert into post</kbd> button is triggering the `click` event on the `#lightbox` div (which has the code to insert the entered text into the the answer box. However, the `#lightbox` div is only responding to a `mousedown` event. I suspect that if the js file was changed to call `mousedown` instead of `click`, everything would work again.

Running this in the console (or with a Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey script) does fix the problem:

```js
$('input[value="Insert into Post"]').click(function() { 
     $("#lightbox").trigger('mousedown');
});
```

Comment: Nice, but then why reassigning hard coded function, only on `lightbox` element does work too?

Comment: @Kaiido No idea, only the devs will know that. My guess is that someone changed the code on the `#lightbox` from `click` to `'mousedown` and broke the chain.