# Do we really need to keep closed typo questions with accepted/upvoted answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've read the rules for the [9 day automatic deletion script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion):

1. Closed more than 9 days ago
2. Not closed as a duplicate
3. Score <= 0
4. Not locked
5. No answers with a score > 0
6. No accepted answer
7. No pending reopen votes
8. No edits in the past 9 days

So what about questions caused by typographical errors? to be more specific, the ones closed citing the following close reason:

[image]

These questions might have accepted as well as upvoted answers which simply points out the typo, hence **will not be deleted** according to rule 5 and 6, by the current script.

Once these questions are closed as typo, has accepted or upvoted answers and there are no edits for the last 9 days <sup>Rule 8</sup>, it probably means that the issue was indeed a typo.

Following are few examples:

- [decode json string failed while firefox firebug can get the right info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24425007/2333214) (*Now deleted, `10k+`*)
- [html in javascript not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402973/html-in-javascript-not-working) (*Now deleted, `10k+`*)
- [execute a function if something is not fulfilled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26448959/2333214)
- [slideToggle not working when link pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24719333/2333214) (*Now deleted, `10k+`*)
- [how to use a JS variable value in getElementsByID?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24720520/2333214) (*Now deleted, `10k+`*)

I do not think such questions or answers will be useful for any future readers. The close reason itself says:

> this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers

Do we really need to keep them...? If not, can we modify the script to delete the typo questions, if there are no significant edits made after closure?

---

The criteria for deletion of such questions I'm suggesting as of now is:

1. Closed more than `n` (*previously 9*) number of days ago
2. Closed as a **Typographical error**
3. <del>Score <= 0</del>
4. Not locked
5. <del>No answers with a score > 0</del>
6. <del>No accepted answer</del>
7. No pending reopen votes
8. No edits in the past 9 days

But it is open for discussion...

---

P.S.: I don't want this discussion ending up removing the close reason itself, or rewording it. No [*cheap fixes*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272711/2333214), please!

Comment: While I would agree in general, I'm not sure if this is the best example since shown from the answer `jQuery's .html is a function, not a variable.` it might have been also a problem in the understanding.

Comment: @bummi An issue caused by such a misunderstanding of the OP is still useless for future readers IMHO...

Comment: How do you suggest the script identify typo questions over other types of questions?

Comment: @Oded closed as typographical error, with no edits or re-open votes for the next 9 days...

Comment: Questions closed with this reason are by definition never going to be useful for other users; deletion should be in order indeed.

Comment: As a 10k user, have you considered writing a query ([noting difficulty with this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202025/213963), though you could still go after old too localized posts easily) and casting delete votes based on that?

Comment: @MichaelT AFAIK The reason why the script was introduced itself is that manually dealing with such questions became hectic and time consuming...

Comment: @TJ true... Side bit to consider, the second example has no accepted answer, and a down vote on the answer with +1 will engage the roomba on it. There are highly scored (and helpful) typo questions that probably shouldn't be deleted automatically. Also, consider answering [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077/289086) from a bit ago where this was brought up.

Comment: @TJ Applying your suggested criteria for deletion would cause auto-deletion **only** question caused by typos.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus No, i didn't mean to change the entire script as per the suggested criteria, I meant to apply the suggested criteria only for the questions closed as **typo**- for the rest of the questions, existing criteria should apply...

Comment: FWIW, if you can find 2 other 10k users to team with you, you can write a DE query to find these questions and just delete them yourself.

Comment: @Mysticial and keep on doing it manually forever...? :) BTW, there are not just one or two such question I'm afraid... At the moment I've 6 delete votes per day...

Comment: @TJ accepted or highly voted are the ones where you need delete votes. If only one answer is at +1, you can downvote it to engage the roomba and make better use of your delete votes. There are also queries to find questions lacking only N delete votes where results are more immediate.

Comment: IMHO, [this kind of question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26133185) is the one that won't be useful to future readers and I very much agree to roomba'd them.

Comment: @AndrewT. haha.. i was thinking about posting an answer addressing few concerns raised in comments with a java `;` example.. BTW, My [typo answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26323743/2333214) just got accepted

Comment: @AndrewT Except it keeps coming up: [SO search - not all are the error, but the majority are](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=else+without+if+%5Bjava%5D). Seems more like something that requires a canonical question and proper duplicate marking.

Comment: Anyone who keeps suggesting queries is really missing the point of a site-wide feature request.

Comment: Question: what is the problem? Why do we need to delete these? This feels an awful lot like some kind of dogmatic adherence to an idea of "what SO is supposed to be for," rather than an actual, practical issue. If there's anything we should all know about software, it's that we should identify the real problem when proposing a solution because we might not always think of the best one.

Comment: @jpmc26 Wait, what? Sorry... I didn't get you..? What does it have to do with deleting questions caused by a typo, which no longer helps anybody else..?

Comment: @TJ I'm saying your question proposes a solution without identifying the problem. You state that we have "questions that are not useful," but who does that harm and how? There may be other ways of dealing with that than deleting the question.

Comment: @jpmc26 Did you actually read why the script was introduced to the system..? This is a proposed enhancement to it. Why do you think there are features in the system for indicating questions and answers as not useful..? Why do you think there are features and scripts running for deleting useless stuff..? What do you think will eventually happen to a website full of junk, which  redirects users to a question just to find a *typo-answer* which doesn't help them regarding the title which attracted them at all..? :/

Comment: related: [Voting stats for “desperate accept” answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254860/839601)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For those worried about letting the roomba loose on **abandoned** (*No edits or re-open votes for `n` number of days*) questions closed as not useful for future readers **by the community**,
Let me address few of the concerns raised here:

---

1. What harm are these questions doing? (*Why delete them at all*).
   --

I managed to get my [typo-fix-answer accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26323626/2333214) within single day after posting this. As of now, the only close vote is mine.

I say it is not going to be useful for anybody else. **No matter whether you downvote or close the question (*or answer*) - according to current system it will never get deleted**.

Okay, So why delete it?

If you look at it, The title reads

> Couldn't make the dropdown flyout close immediately after radio is selected.

The only ones likely to visit the question is probably having trouble with their dropdown. (*Oh, I forgot those fighting our `~10k` close vote queue, <sub>[image: fighting]</sub>  sorry*)

We'll only cause frustration to `99.9%` of those trying to fix their dropdown by keeping such a question with a typo solution.

Think about how many of these are out there, not even closed...

I hope we all can agree that there is no point in keeping such typos. I say we unleash roomba upon them.

---

So the next concern is:

> this close reason is often misused to close syntax-related issues and not true typos.

There are two points here - **Syntax errors** and **Misuse of close reason**.

2. Let's consider syntax errors.

---

Assume there is a method called `print()` in a programming language `X` that prints a string which is passed to it.

- Someone randomly tries to print a message like `print[0]` - doesn't work, posts on SO without any sort of research.
- Somebody else does the same trying to print a message like `print -->  msg` at some other point of time.
- Somebody else does the same trying to print a message like `print "msg"`.
- Somebody else does the same trying to print a message like `print>>"msg"`.
- Somebody else does the same trying to print a message like `print{"msg"}`.

and it goes on...

What we can do?

Close them all as duplicate of a canonical question! [image]

Ohkey.What should be a good canonical question that will help such users?

- Option 1 (*I'll come back to why I even posted this later*):

> Q: <del>Ways in which you should not try to print a message in language X</del>
>
> A: You should not do `print "msg", instead do print("msg")` // posted in 2010
>
> A: You should not do `print{msg}, instead do print(msg)` // posted 2011
>
> A: You should not do `print-->msg, instead do print(msg)` // " 2012
>
> A: You should not do `print>>msg, instead do print(msg)` // " 2013
>
> .
>
> .
> A: You should not do `print[msg], instead do print(msg)` // " 2020
>
> And so on...

What's the point? the answer is always `print(msg)`.

What is the issue..? lack of minimal knowledge, research effort, enthusiasm, etc. which we should not be encouraging as a community for *professional and enthusiastic programmers*.

- Option 2:

A canonical question, something along:

> Q: "How to print a message using X".
>
> A: You can print a message using the print() method like print("hi").

Ohkay, now we have a canonical question.

But there is still an issue here - Unlike other scenarios, when will this ever end? This will never stop as long as new people learns language `X`.

In general, Any of the users who searches `print not working in X` will find our canonical question - So unlike other scenarios where duplicate questions having different titles act as signposts to our canonical questions, there is **No** need of thousand duplicates in these cases IMHO.

Is there any point in keep on closing **thousands of such questions** as duplicates, duplicate of duplicates, and their duplicate **manually** forever, and **keeping** them?

NO - My humble opinion.

Besides, What we're effectively doing **by keeping all possible question as duplicate for each scenario where the answer is a simple one liner is - choosing the Option 1 above.**

We should help the user by answering it or direct the user to our canonical question where he can find the answer.

### And then, burn the question, since it is not useful for future readers.

Okay, I see still some are worried about **few exceptional syntax errors** that happens too often, in that case please read on to the next section:

---

3. Now let's talk about close reason being misused.

---

There is one thing I'd like to remind you at this point (*One of the best, and strongest feature of StackOverflow, IMHO*):

[image]

Let us consider our `print()` method in language `X`.

I do not know language `X` - So I'm not even going to see it.

The ones who visits it are probably the ones familiar with language `X`. The ones who can answer it, or identify that it is a silly mistake which is not going to help future readers are probably more than familiar with language `X`.

Now a **`3k+` user who votes to close citing it is not going to be useful for future readers are probably the ones which are familiar with the language `X`, as well as StackOverflow**.
who loves being part of this community, and wish to keep it clean.

Rest of the `3k+` users who visits such a closed question and doesn't think it is worth re-opening for the next `n` number of days are also the type of users mentioned above.

**Please read the following over and over again** (*Until you actually get what types of questions will become eligible for deletion*)

According to our proposal, a question becomes eligible for deletion when 5  such `3k+` users indicated that the question is not useful for future readers, and the rest silently agreed with it by not voting to re-open it, along with the original poster who abandoned it by not even trying to improve it. All I have to say is

### Trust the community.

If you don't trust the community. then that means there is something wrong with the system. Maybe it's time to discuss why we no longer trust our community..?

Not satisfied..? Ohkay, what if, in case, somehow a good question gets closed..?

- Anybody who thinks it is likely to help the community can edit (*or suggest an edit*) to improve it.
- Anybody (*3k+*) who thinks the same can vote to reopen it.

Now what if, anybody who thinks the question had some amount of value finds it after deletion?

- Either the anybody above is a `10k` user - He can vote to undelete it
- Or he is the OP - He can flag for moderation attention citing why his question was useful -

  Now the above is extremely unlikely to happen since we are talking about deleting **abandoned** questions with no edits or votes to re-open for `n` number of days.

Now let me repeat -The *anybody* I was talking about is part of the community.

### Trust the community.

---

### UPDATE:

It seems there are concerns regarding the criteria.

1. **Isn't the upvote on the answer indicating that it's useful?**

Not particularly in this case: The upvotes on *fixed-your-typo* answers mostly indicates that the answer indeed solves the problem, and some times it indicates that the answerer was the fastest gun as well [image].

We should not bother about the upvotes on *typo-answers*.

If you had looked at my [*original example*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402973/html-in-javascript-not-working) (*Now deleted, `10k+`*), even the upvoted answerer voted to close the question. (*I do this as well, answering such questions will indicate that it is solved and might save somebody else's time which they can spent answering other useful questions*)

---

2. **Isn't the upvote on question indicating that it is useful?**.

Okay, this one is thought.

If you look at the history of question - Initially this criteria was not striked out.

I wanted a discussion to happen regarding this, hence I wrote *Not sure regarding this* - Until someone dare to strike it out saying it should not be a criteria, Which made me think about it - Yes, it should not be a criteria, because:

- I find myself upvoting questions which I couldn't solve - Because I'd like to know how it can be solved, As well as I'd like to invite experts here (*damn, I was blind*)
- Upvotes are *way liberal* - They are anonymous, only requires 15rep, and it takes hardly a second.
- The ones who upvoted and moved on might not come back to see what happened to the question, even if they does, the 5 minute freezing period to take the upvote back would've probably expired. (*Who will bother editing a typo question to take your upvote back?*)
- Close votes are different - It is **not anonymous**. takes time, and you better have a good reason or the rest of them might take it up with you - You might even become a target for a moderator's eye.
- Close votes citing the reason in discussion mostly occur after the question is solved - which ended up as a typo.

So I'm weighing close votes from `3k+` users familiar with the topic over anonymous upvotes on question, as of now...

Comment: On syntax errors, I think some syntax errors are more common than others so while I don't think you need to (nor can you) cover every possible syntax error that can be made, a few common ones - like mistaking `html` for a property instead of a function in `jQuery` may be common enough to have some value.

Comment: @MattBurland Which is why i said - **Trust the Community** - the community knows such useful exceptions, and will keep them.

Comment: Isn't the presence of an upvoted answer *trusting the community*? Maybe you could discount the asker's vote and say if it has a +2 then at least somebody other than the asker found it useful.

Comment: @MattBurland No, people upvote `typo-answers` to indicate that it solves the issue, and of course - the answerer was the fastest gun. :)

Comment: @TJ "trust the community" works fine when the content isn't removed as a result of those actions automatically. As I mention in my edited answer, you can close a question for this reason with exactly 1 close vote (although pretty unlikely). To automatically assume that 1 person (or more realistically 2 to 3) can decide the fate of a question within 9 days is too aggressive. There needs to be some level of control.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I changed the inactive duration to `n` in the original post...

Comment: Perhaps we could set a minimum amount of question votes, for example `>10` which would prevent automatic deletion. I can't speak for the tags that I don't frequent, but on the ones I do I rarely see typo questions having a score of more than 2. Past a certain threshold, which would have to be determined by people with access to more data than me, the question is likely to have enough going on to potentially be helpful perhaps with a title change.

Answer (score 19):

If the post is truly never going to help anyone, then deleting may help clean up the site regardless of answers.

My issue is letting the roomba loose on on these questions assumes the close reason is correct.  I think this close reason is often misused to close syntax-related issues and not true typos.  Your [original example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402973/html-in-javascript-not-working) would appear to be more of a syntax error than a typo although that is tough to say for certain based on the OP's limited feedback.  While making syntax questions searchable is difficult, it stands to reason they may have some value for learners of a language, so just deleting them without human intervention would be a mistake.

---

To make my concerns more clear, the suggestion here is talking about eliminated the 3 most common control for protecting a question from automatic deletion.  Automatic anything needs to be almost foolproof as once it is gone, there is virtually no chance of it coming back.

It only takes 5 users to close a question, and given the majority rules, it really only takes 2-3 users to close a question as a typo question, and it is even possible with 1 close vote assuming the unlikely chance that you get a questions with 5 different close types and the first type is a typo question.

Add in that Stack Overflow has 2 major issues to contend with

- A massive question volume
- A massive influx of crap

There is too much to worry about to fix wrongly closed questions.  In fact, we have encouraged users not to worry about questions closed for the wrong reason because there are other things to worry about, so any argument that if it is ok to delete wasn't acted on before deletion after only 9 days is bullcrap.

There needs to be sufficient controls to prevent automatic deletion so we can be assured that a sufficient number of users agree that the question is not worth saving.  There needs to be more controls to replace the controls that are getting removed to add some level of consensus to the deletion.

- Extend the timeline to 30 days.  9 days is simply not enough
- Require at least 4 votes for typo to be eligible for automatic deletion and not just the normal majority with earliest date breaking ties
- Add a 10K queue (or another similar rep level - something much more than 3K) to review questions that are about to be deleted for this reason.  This would at least ensure some experienced users saw the question and agreed that it needs to be deleted.

Comment: There can be **infinite** number of possible syntax errors... i don't see much value by keeping syntax errors... That is clearly an issue with lack of minimal knowledge...

Comment: Think about the number of ways in which you can make a syntax error in a simple `for` loop.. are you saying that keeping a question for each scenario is going to help beginners..? **No** - We just one question: *How to write a for loop*. There are documentations and tutorials as well...

Comment: I agree with your worry about the close reason being correct, but I still think the roomba is worth turning loose on these questions -- but the 30 day model rather than the 9. That should be plenty of time for anyone concerned to have clarified if necessary.

Comment: @TJ: for you and me syntax errors are trivial errors (unless a compiler produces 300 pages of some template type) but for a beginner it might be a real hurdle e.g., `print` statement in Python 2 vs. `print()` function in Python 3: many people (unfamiliar with Python) run Python 2 scripts on Python 3 interpreter and get `SyntaxError`: there should be one canonical question that explains the issue (everything else should be closed as duplicates) -- none should be deleted.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian that is precisely the issue - how will you create canonical questions for all possible syntax errors..? Like i said earlier, there can be infinite number of syntax errors... I can make syntax error in that `print()` function like `pirnt()`, `pinrt()`, `pintr()`, `iprnt()`, `prnit()`... so on. Considering the number of such possibilities and a few lines of code, how likely is another user creating the same error and ending up in the corresponding question..? What is the point in keeping them..?

Comment: ..  Most of the languages will produce an error message in such cases... we can have a canonical question regarding that error message - whose answer is something like *"this error message is thrown when you have a syntax error"*. Check for syntax errors in your code... other than that, i see no point in keeping a question for each instance... because in general there are infinite number of ways to produce the common errors...

Comment: the reality disagrees with you. Some errors are *much more* likely then the others. And how do we find out which errors are common? -- people ask questions about such errors. `print "a"` vs. `print("a")` is *not* a random typo. The very fact that you *do not* understand it (and whoever upvoted your comment) tells me you should not be allowed to moderate such questions

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The thing you need to realize is - firstly, if it is a good question, such questions will not be closed. secondly if it is a good question, it will not be abandoned. Finally, trust the 5 `3k+` users who voted to close it, and the rest of thousands who didn't bother to open it and the OP who abandoned it. If the question has any value - all these are very unlikely to happen all together, if it does happen once among a million question, whoever thinks it has any value can vote to undelete it (`10k`+), or flag for mod attention.

Comment: Nobody is talking about blindly deleting all typo questions automatically. There is a level of human effort and judgement before the question becomes a candidate for deletion. If the community doesn't trust the users who voted to close the question sighting it is not going to be useful for anyone else, and the rest who agreed, including the OP -by not makeing any effort to re-open, then why give them the privilege..?

Comment: @TJ Jumping back a few comments, if you have a canonical answer (for say the error message), than why are you closing as typo instead of as a duplicate? For reference, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826948/syntax-error-on-print-with-python-3?rq=1) is the canonical question for `print` vs `print()`.

Comment: @thegrinner nobody is suggesting to delete anything that can act as a canonical question. **This request completely depends on the community itself to make that decision**... I'm tired of replying to individual comments so I posted my thoughts as an answer...

Comment: `My issue is letting the roomba loose on on these questions assumes the close reason is correct.` -- Then allow 30 days for the community to review them.  30 days really ought to be enough to reverse an invalid close reason, assuming the question is worth preserving (most closed questions are not, unless they are improved by editing).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm sorry, but that is BS.  Given the volume of Stack Overflow stuff gets lost to the users that can do anything about it but the question at least exists for searching.  I'm not objecting to deletion of crap, I'm objecting to the deletion of questions that only 5 people decided was a typo within 9 days.  Stretch out the timeline to 30 days and add some more human intervention (a pending deletion queue for 10K users?) and maybe you have something.... but to unilaterally say that any question closed with a specific close reason will be deleted within 9 days is not a good decision.

Comment: @psubsee2003  While I agree with the first two points, I personally don't like introducing another queue to showcase all the crap -_- ... If the question has any value, then it's pretty easy for anyone to rescue it - `2k+` can simply make an edit to improve it, rest can suggest an edit.. nothing to edit: it's pretty easy to find someone to caste a reopen vote in chat room... why introduce another  crap queue to waste time...

Comment: @TJ fair enough ,that was just an idea to ensure you have enough eyes on the post.  The first 2 points are the most important and would address my concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I support this, except that I think the `score <= 0` requirement should be kept.

If it has a positive score, obviously someone found it to be a good or useful question, and so others might as well. Remember, the close-voters are only human, and might think it is useless when in fact it can help future readers.

Comment: This is indeed a good point... I posted the reasoning why i thought we shouldn't consider them... It is totally up to the community to decide...

Comment: `score<=0` is a slippery requirement, as it ignores [natural romance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254860/839601 "discussed eg here") between asker and answerer. Score 2 or higher guarantees that someone else besides them found the post useful - note how [recent proposal to improve auto-deletion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077/839601) suggests to qualify by _"no answers with a score **> 1**"_

Answer (score -7):

Disagree.

#### Reason

I think the basic problem with doing this is simple: an automated delete system has no way of determining the value of the *answer*. That's part of the reason questions with upvoted answers won't get deleted. Obviously, *someone* thought it was valuable enough to upvote it. Terrible questions sometimes spawn truly great answers, and the site shouldn't be automatically deleting them just because the question was closed as a typo.

That line of reasoning compeltely ignores the issue of what to do with the reputation the answerer earned, which is another discussion in its own right.

#### Addressing the real issue

The question I would pose to proponents is, "What harm are these questions doing?" The site should generally leave things alone unless they actually do some kind of harm, and whenever possible, that harm should be addressed without deleting content.

If the answer and question really provide no value and are doing some kind of harm, this should require manual clean up, with an actual person making a call about whether the answer is valuable.

In other words, I'm reversing your question. Do we really need to delete them?

Comment: *"Terrible questions sometimes spawn truly great answers"*  - Such questions will be improved, most often by the user who took time to provide the great answer, or by the community who finds the answer to be useful - Hence will never become a target for deletion. Moreover, if the answer for the question is something great, rather than a typo, nobody in there right mind will vote to close it.

Comment: ... *"What harm are these questions doing?"* - already replied for your comment below the original post... In short words - There is a reason why the automatic script was introduced in existing system. Please go and find out... I don't want to repeat it here...

Comment: "*ignores the issue of what to do with the reputation the answerer earned"* - I expected this from somebody... You worried about the rep from typo answers..? Oh oh.. No matter how good your answer is, if the question is deleted for a reason (*Say user deleted*) you lose the respective rep. [That is by design](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/256148) - I don't think it is a significant point regarding this feature request at all..

Comment: "*Obviously, someone thought it was valuable enough to upvote it.*" Often the question asker will upvote it because it helped them solve their problem. That doesn't mean it will be useful to anyone else.

Comment: @DonaldDuck SO has much, much bigger systemic problems to worry about right now, like a staff and moderator team dedicated to class warfare propagandized as opposing "rudeness."